# What are the use-cases for view-binding and data-binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

Early this year (2019), Google introduced [view-binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), a new feature that allows smooth binding of UI components to data sources, just like [data-binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).

I went through the documentation for view-binding and I couldn't quite find any difference between view-binding and the widely-known data-binding in terms of use-case; they seem to do the exact same thing.

Do they have separate use-cases? Where is the line drawn? Was view-binding introduced so that data-binding could be deprecated?

**PS:** 
 While drafting this question, I tried to make sure I wasn't asking an opinion-based question. I just want to understand the use-cases for both libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the way they work, **the major difference between them is speed**.

The ViewBinding API is way faster than the DataBinding library because viewBinding does not involve annotation processing underneath. This is the major advantage of view-binding over data-binding, and also why it is considered more efficient.

However, one major thumb-down for view-binding is the fact that it does not support binding-expressions (yet).

> Where is the line drawn?

Due to the difference in speed/efficiency, view-binding is preferential to data-binding **for large projects**. Build time would be optimal since there is no annotation processing being done under the hood.

> Was view-binding introduced so that data-binding could be deprecated?

Quite frankly, it's not clear yet. But at this moment, they are two mutually exclusive libraries.

Here's [an article](https://proandroiddev.com/new-in-android-viewbindings-the-difference-from-databinding-library-bef5945baf5e) that sheds more light on the similarities and differences.